# How to Archive a Site as a Sub Site

Tags: 2010, powershell, sub-site, archive

I'm having a tough time cracking this and need some assistance. Below is a site called TestSite, that is used to archive other sites not in use located at `contoso.com/sites/Prong2/JRS/testsite/default.aspx`:

[image]

I want to **archive** a site called Sporting Goods, which resides in another site collection, as a subsite that will be located at the **Sites and Workspaces** section along with the subsite Archive Test shown below:

[image]

I am familiar with the Powershell cmdlets to export and import a site but I came across a problem I need assistance with. For some reason when I export a site, the site that I exported is still available in the original location that it was from. My understanding is when I export a site using Powershell that it would remove the site from its original location. Can someone clarify why it isn't so? Lastly, is there a cmdlet I can use to archive a site as a subsite? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Exporting isn't a cut/paste operation, it is a copy/paste operation. When you are done with the export/import process, you'll want to then use the [remove-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607890(v=office.14).aspx) or [remove-spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607948(v=office.14).aspx) to delete the old site.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know of a way to import a site as a subsite to TestSite that I have above in my initial query? I have tried the import and I messed up and it imported a site on top of another site (copy&paste). I want to import a site (Sporting Goods) and make it a subsite of TestSite. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require PowerShell, then you can use SharePoint's ***"Content and Structure"*** aka ***"Site Manager"*** to move a subsite from its current location to a new location.

In the root site, go to `Site Settings > Site Administration > Content and Structure.`

Use the Site Manager interface to select the site, move the site, and select a destination.

Note that if you don't see the ***"Content and Structure"*** option in site settings, you'll need to activate the ***"SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"*** Site Collection Feature.

Comment: My dilemma here is that the site called Sporting Goods belongs to a different Site Collection. Any suggestions on how I can move a site called Sporting Goods from Site Collection A as a subsite to a site called TestSite in Site Collection B for example? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Crossing site collections was not clear in your question.  The Site Manager won't work across site collections thus your options are to continue with export/import process you are defining or start looking to a 3rd Party solution like ShareGate's migration tool for example.